# I want to add multiple comments to my Article (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am creating a website and I want to seed some data.

I want to create two articles with two comments each  :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Article = require("./models/articles.js"),
    Comment = require("./models/comments.js");

var articleData = [
    {
        title: "Fast Cars",
        author: "Steve Novak",
        company: "AthLead",
        body: "SOME TEXT"
    },
    {
        title: "New Design",
        author: "Kevin Garnett",
        company: "Revoos",
        body: "COOL ARTICLE"
    }
];

var commentData = [
    {
        body: "I really love the new design",
        author: "Mark Cuban"
    },
    {
        body: "This is hitting my funny bone",
        author: "Lisa Jones"
    }
];
```

I am Deleting all past comments and articles.

Then for each article I am first creating the article and then pushing two comments.

I am getting a problem at saving the newly formed article to the database :

Placing article.save() at 1. causes parallel save() error to occur

Whereas placing at 2. causes no comment to be saved.

```
function seedDB() {
    Comment.deleteMany({}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        Article.deleteMany({}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

                articleData.forEach(function (article) {
                    Article.create(article, function (err, article) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            commentData.forEach(function(comment) {
                                Comment.create(comment, function (err, comment) {
                                    if (err)
                                        console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        article.comments.push(comment);
                                        //     PROBLEM
                                        // 1. article.save();
                                    }

                                })
                            })
                            // PROBLEM
                            //2. article.save();
                        }
                    });
                });

            });


        });
    });

    console.log("Database Reset");
}



module.exports = seedDB;
```

Comment: Please, can you share your article and comment schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently in [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) and using `async/await` willl go a long way making your code readable and thus makes it easy to debug.

Consider the following workflow that uses `async/await`

```
async function seedDB() {
    try {
        // clean up all comments
        await Comment.deleteMany({}).exec()

        // clean up all articles
        await Article.deleteMany({}).exec()

        // create articles
        await Article.create(articleData)

        // create comments 
        const comments = await Comment.create(commentData)

        // update articles with the new comments
        const updatedArticles = await Article.updateMany(
            {}, 
            { '$set': { comments } }
        ).exec()

        console.log(updatedArticles)

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of documents to [`Model.create`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create), just create `comments` first then use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from `articletData` with `comments` assigned to each article

using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
async function seedDB() {

  ...

  const comments = await Comment.create(commentData);
  const articles = await Article.create(articleData.map(article => { article.comments = comments; return article }));
  ...
```

using [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
function seedDB() {

  ...

  Comment.create(commentData).then(comments => 
    Article.create(articleData.map(article => { article.comments = comments; return article })).then(articles => {
    
    });
  });
  
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first `Article.create...`, on successfull creation the function returns the **article** object or a error on the other side.

You need to run the forEach loop in the newly created article for achieve each article contain the Comments.

you need to work with the existed newly created article data.

Example

```
articleData.forEach(function (article) {
  Article.create(article, function (err, article) {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err);
    } else {
      article.update(
       { "_id": ObjectId(article.id) },
       { $push: { comments: commentData } }
      );
      // OR try something like 
      // article.comments = commentData
      // OR
      // article.comments.insert(commentData)
      article.save();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I need to store the comments in the database too instead of just pushing them in the article collections

Comment: article.save() store the data in the database!